# how to set populate checkbox is checked(true) in gridview from action button click

Tags: c#

I have a gridview with option checkbox. when i choose a row with checked checkbox and then i press button
send to update data with parameter option checkbox is checked. and then my question is, 
how to set populate checkbox is checked(true) in gridview from action button click.

this is my view.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvInquiryDocument"> 
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick="checkAll(this);" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkSelect" runat="server" onclick="Check_Click(this)" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID" Visible="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="hdGetId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ANO") %>'
                                    Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeliveryBy" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeliveryBy") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPolicyNo" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PolicyNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

this is my .cs

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DMSStatus dmsStatus = new DMSStatus();

        foreach (GridViewRow di in gvInquiryDocument.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                TextBox tx = (TextBox)di.FindControl("hdGetId");
                var Ano = Server.HtmlDecode(tx.Text.Trim());
                TextBox txtPolicyNo = (TextBox)di.FindControl("txtPolicyNo");
                var PolicyNo = Server.HtmlDecode(txtPolicyNo.Text.Trim()); 

                dmsStatus.ANO = Convert.ToInt16(Ano);
                dmsStatus.PolicyNo = PolicyNo; 
                dmsStatus.UpdateData();

                bindData();                
                //i want to set code after binddata....
            } 
        }           
    }

private void bindData()
{
    DMSStatus dmsStatus = new DMSStatus();            
    DataSet ds = dmsStatus.GetData(); 
    gvInquiryDocument.DataSource = ds;
    gvInquiryDocument.DataBind(); 
}
```

please give me solution.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer for what you are working on, but here is one solution available. If you are able to use AJAX calls on your website, and if you want to use a little JQuery below is one way to approach saving a list of values from checked grid view rows, in java script, then uses AJAX to send those IDs to your website to do something with the collection.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function btnSend(sender, args){
        var idCollection = new Array();
        $('#<%=gvInquiryDocument.ClientID%>').find("input:checkbox").each(function () {
            if (this.checked) { 
                //Find the ID value in the row by cell index
                idCollection.push(this.parentElement.cells[3].innerHTML )
            }
        }

    myWebServiceInterfaceClass.MyWebsiteServiceProxy.UpdateIdCollection(idCollection, SaveResults , ProxyCallFailed);
}

    function SaveResults(results){
        //If you want to send anything back to the site and do something after updating the ids
        //Or just refresh the page and let the onload event repopulate your grid on postback
    }

    function ProxyCallFailed(){
        //Something bad happened on your ajax call 
    }
```

Comment: any other idea ? because im not familiar with AJAX. please give me sample url or others to fix my problems. thanks...